# Stuck on Asus boot logo after flash Lineage OS

Tags: lineageos

I have flashed my **Asus Zenfone Max ZC550KL** with **lineage-14.1-20170406-Z010D.zip** and **Open Gapps x64  7.1 stock** version.

After successful installation of both it gets **stuck on asus boot logo**

Answer (score 2):

If you are flashing a stock ROM for the first time, it takes a considerable amount of time to boot up. You could:

- Try waiting a little longer(10-15 minutes)
- Flash the ROM only without the GAPPS and boot
- Try another Custom ROM

If it boots up up without flashing GAPPS, then you  should probably use a lighter version of it, either

`pico` or `nano`